# Linking TeamCity 8.0.5 to MySQL

Tags: mysql, linux, teamcity

I'm having troubles to link TeamCity 8.0.5 to mysql.
This seem wrong/outdated/whatever: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Setting+up+an+External+Database

I don't have a config folder in my teamcityinstallfolder.
I don't have a lib/jbdc to put the the .jar
Do I have to create the jbdc folder ?
Then, how will it know the credentials to connect to my teamcity user account I created ?
I need to hand this project today, so please, please, show me how you done it.

Can anyone help ? How do you set it up correctly ?
I am a sysadmin, was asked to do a script to automate all this but if someone who set up teamcity with mySQL could help me, it would be really nice

I need this on LINUX, not Windows, please, anyone :'(

Answer (score 0):

Those folders are not under the TeamCity install folder, they're under ProgramData.
On Windows 7 for example they're under the **C:\ProgramData\JetBrains\TeamCity** folder for TeamCity.

Comment: I need this on Linux, please anyone ;'(

Comment: Is your TeamCity up and running right now? Because if you go to the web admin site and go to Administration> Global Settings, I think it might confirm for you the path for the Data Directory.

Comment: Well I've been trying to set it up with mySQL and it always crash.. will try that. Just tried: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/TeamCity+Data+Directory, funny thing is when I get to the install display it tells me it's in .root/Buildserver I created the whole thing and it tells me it's empty.